# "list iterator is not incrementable" only on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, exception, iterator

I'm currently facing a strange problem: I have a std::list of pointers and I want to clear it and to delete all of its items.

So, I've written a small piece of code:

```
for (std::list<IClientSocket *>::iterator it = mClients.begin(); it != mClients.end(); it = mClients.erase(it))
  delete *it;
```

I've never had problems with this code when I run it on Linux, but on Windows I get an exception `list iterator is not incrementable`.

I've tried differend alternatives (using `while (!list.empty())` or `pop_back` instead of iterators), but I got the same issue.
The only solution I've found is to erase the item before deleting the pointer it contains:

```
 std::list<IClientSocket *>::iterator it = mClients.begin();
 std::list<IClientSocket *>::iterator end = mClients.end();

 while (it != end) {
   IClientSocket *client = *it;
   it = mClients.erase();
   delete client;
 }
```

I can't understand why I get this exception. I've read that erase invalidate the iterator, but delete don't (this is quite logical)...
Moreover, when i run the program via VisualStudio, it raises the exception. But when i run the same program on Cygwin, it works fine...

Have I missed something?

Comment: `std::list::erase()` has mandatory parameters. This code would also disappear completely if you made use of something that cleans itself up.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my Visual Studio (using a `std::list<int *>`).

Comment: @Cyber: I can see no place in the shown code where Simon uses a deleted iterator. Notice that the increment part of the for loop is `it = mClients.erase(it)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"list iterator is not incrementable" is a bit of a tip-off. You don't show all your code, and in particular there's no list iterator increment shown. Apparently that's happening inside the `delete` then. You're not by any chance trying to iterate over the container when you're in the dtor of one of its elements?

Comment: You're right. The error is inside the destructor of the deleted item. Thx!